# Heading of Environment protrudes

Tags: environments, indentation

I am defining a new environment but the heading of the environment protrudes and even after including \noindent in the post-environment braces, the first line of the following paragraph starts after a space of one letter.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames, twoside, openany,reqno, 12pt, final, fleqn, ocgcolorlinks]{amsbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}



\makeatletter

\newcounter{Axiom} %counter for example
\newenvironment{Axiom} %name of environment
 [1] %number of arguments for the environment
 []
{\begin{trivlist}\refstepcounter{Axiom}%be able to label
 \item[{\@ifnotempty{#1}{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1-}}}\textcolor{red}{\textbf{Axiom~\theAxiom:}}}]%Title
}%font for body of example
{\end{trivlist}\par%new paragraph when the body of Axiom ends
\noindent\ignorespaces%stop anymore indentation
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is just three lines of text. A very much dummy text because the lipsum text is very lengthy even with the parameters 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 et cetera. See My-Axioms goes outside the margin.
\begin{Axiom}[My]
This is just three lines of text. A very much dummy text because the lipsum text is very lengthy even with the parameters 1-2, 2-3, 3-4 et cetera. 
\end{Axiom}
This is my typing. It is easily seen that there is a space before ``T'' even after \verb+\noindent+ is supplied in the environment. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is better not to use `\noindent` but as you do replace `\ignorespaces` by `\ignorespacesafterend` here

Comment: ```\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%stop anymore indentation```
removes the space before "T".  But If I remove ```\noindent``` , then the next line is indented.

Comment: yes because you added `\par`. Latex lists automatically suppress indentation if they start mid paragraph, by starting the next paragraph with `\noindent`you force a paragraph there so if the following thing is another list, or a blank line or anything other than text, you will get a spurious empty paragraph.

Comment: why not use `\newtheorem` here?

Comment: @David Carlisle 
I wrote 
```{\end{trivlist}%\par%new paragraph when the body of Axiom ends
%\noindent\ignorespacesafterend%stop anymore indentation
}``` 
and it worked. 

The reason for defining new environment is that I want to prefix Axiom with some word like Geometry-Axiom 1: Set-Axiom 1: etc.